# How to hide an onclick button inside ajax response?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Could anyone tell me how i can hide/remove loadmore button when I receive certain response from ajax call(for example i got undefined or null value) ?I tried to use  $('#mango').hide(); but it didn't remove the button for me!But I received the alert which confirms that i got null or undefined value from api. Hope some one help me fix this .Thanks

code:

```
<script>
var maxnumId = null;
function callApi() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "https://api.somesite.com/......"),
        success: function(data) {
      maxnumId = data.pagination.next_num_id;

          if (maxnumId === undefined || maxnumId === null) {

                alert('End!');
                 //remove the loadmore button here
                    $('#mango').hide();
               }
        }

    });
}
</script>
<body>
<br>
<center>

<button id="mango" onclick="callApi()">Load More</button>

</html>
```

Comment: What is `maxnumId` value? Does it say `undefined` or `null` in the console?

Comment: .hide() hides the element. .remove(), removes it from the DOM.

Comment: have you tried with remove? can you write your html code?

Comment: thanks for reply. I get the alert that maxnumId is null but the the button is still there ! how i can remove it via dom ?

Comment: Have you checked if you're loading jquery before executing your script?

Comment: @rui silva jquery is working since i get response from ajax and can display them in alert!(maxnumId values)

Comment: You could instead change the css of the element with the ID mango to display:none, can you check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the if condition is met (`maxnumId === undefined || maxnumId === null`), you could try to do it in plain js:

```
document.getElementById('mango').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('mango').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Many thanks all for replies. Leandro Gabriel Casas your solution worked!